# Why am I getting an error when creating a new controller in Symfony?

Tags: symfony5

There is a project that needs to be finalized. When creating a new controller using the existing namespace, I get an error

```
Fatal error: Uncaught Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\Exception\InvalidArgumentException: Expected to find class "App\Controller\MyController" in file "/var/www/app/src/Controller/MyController.php" while importing services from resource "../src/*", but it was not found! Check the namespace prefix used with the resource.
```

It's strange that with `TestController` everything works fine

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution:

After creating a valid controller, you need to open any page
Add methods one at a time and open any page after each